# PYTHON Регулярные выражения: нечётное число-чётное число

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка с числами. Нужно написать регулярное выражение, которое, если число состоит из нечётного-чётного-нечётного-чётного... числа выводит его
Пример:

> 12 23 3456 789 123456 --> 12 3456 123456

Я сделал это:

```
print(re.findall(r'[13579][02468]',string))
```

Но результат не совсем тот:

```
12 34 56 78 12 34 56
```

---

Попробовал так:

```
print(re.findall(r'[13579][02468]\w+',text[0]))
```

Теперь результат следующий:

```
3456 789 123456
```

Почему-то пропало 12. А ещё не нужно, чтобы выводилось 789, ибо там 78 попадает под шаблон, а вот для 9 нету пары

---

Как доделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print(re.findall(r'\b(?:[13579][02468])+\b',string))
```

`\b ... \b` означает, что мы ищем целое "слово" (в данном случае состоящее из цифр)

`([13579][02468])+` означает, что мы ищем числа, состоящие из пар нечетная-четная

`?:` в начале скобки означает, что она не будет запомнена